# Is the expected value continuous in some sense?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, random-variables

For example if we have the space of random variables $L^1$.

Then we should have that $|E(X-Y)| \le ||X-Y||_{L^1}$, right?- So, this would mean, that the expected value is Lipschitz continuous, correct?

Comment: In the L^1-norm X need not be bounded but must be absolutely integrable. In both cases E(X) is a bounded linear functional with bound 1 and this property is sufficient to obtain the inequality. In fact bounded and continuous linear functionals on a normed space coincide.

Comment: Summarising this, so on L1 the expectation value is continuous, right?

Comment: @Lipschitz Yes, you are right. The expected value is Lipschitz continuous with respect to the metric $\operatorname E|X-Y|$ for $X,Y\in L^1$ since $|\operatorname EX-\operatorname EY|\le\operatorname E|X-Y|$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could say that the expected value is continuous in the sense that if $\operatorname E|X_n-X|^r\to0$, then $\operatorname E|X_n|^r\to\operatorname E|X|^r$ since
$$
|(\operatorname E|X_n|^r)^{1/r}-(\operatorname E|X|^r)^{1/r}|\le(\operatorname E|X_n-X|^r)^{1/r}
$$
for $r\ge1$ using the reverse triangle inequality for the norm $\|\cdot\|_{L^r}=(\operatorname E|\cdot|^r)^{1/r}$.

Comment: but $(E|X_n-X|^r)^{\frac{1}{r}} = ||X_n-X||_{L^r}$, right?, so the answer would be, that the expected value would even be Lipschitz continuous with constant $L=1$, in this sense.

Comment: @Lipschitz The norm $\|\cdot\|_{L^r}$ is Lipschitz continuous with the constant equal to $1$.